# ExtJS4 - multi-file upload and get file path of the uploaded images after uploading

Tags: php, json, extjs, file-upload

I am building an ExtJS4 web application and I have a part where I can successfully upload multiple files in a folder in my file director. I used [Ivan Novakov's library](https://github.com/ivan-novakov/extjs-upload-widget) to achieve this.

I created a button and in that button's handler, I had this code:

```
var uploadPanel = Ext.create('Ext.ux.upload.Panel', {
    uploader : 'Ext.ux.upload.uploader.FormDataUploader',
    uploaderOptions : {
        url : 'uploadGallery.php'
    },
    synchronous : true
});

var uploadDialog = Ext.create('Ext.ux.upload.Dialog', {
    dialogTitle : 'My Upload Dialog',
    panel : uploadPanel
});



this.mon(uploadDialog, 'uploadcomplete', function(uploadPanel, manager, items, errorCount) {

    console.log('manager = ' + manager);
    console.log('items = ' + items);

    console.log('manager result = ' + manager.result);
    console.log('manager result message = ' + manager.message);
    console.log('manager status = ' + manager.status);
    console.log('manager filePath = ' + manager.filePath);

}, this);

uploadDialog.show();
```

I have my own PHP file upload handler as such:

```
<?php

require_once '_common.php';
$config = require_once '_config.php'; //require __DIR__ . '/_config.php';
$fileName = '';
$mimeType = '';
$fileSize = 0;

if (empty($_FILES)) {
    _error('No file received');
}

$pathArray = array();

foreach ($_FILES as $fileName => $fileData) {

        if (
            !isset($fileData['error']) ||
            is_array($fileData['error'])
        ) {
            die(json_encode(array(
                'success' => false,
                'status' => "Invalid Parameters.",
                'files' => $_FILES 
            )));
        }

        // Check $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] value.
        switch ($fileData['error']) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:

                die(json_encode(array(
                    'success' => false,
                    'status' => "No file sent.",
                    'files' => $_FILES
                )));

            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                die(json_encode(array(
                    'success' => false,
                    'status' => "Exceeded filesize limit.",
                    'files' => $_FILES
                )));

            default:
                die(json_encode(array(
                    'success' => false,
                    'status' => "Unknown errors.",
                    'files' => $_FILES
                )));
        }

        // You should also check filesize here. 
        if ($fileData['size'] > 1000000) {
                die(json_encode(array(
                    'success' => false,
                    'status' => "Exceeded File Size Limit.",
                    'files' => $_FILES
                )));
        }

        // DO NOT TRUST $_FILES['fileToUpload']['mime'] VALUE !!
        // Check MIME Type by yourself.
        $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
        if (false === $ext = array_search(
            $finfo->file($fileData['tmp_name']),
            array(
                'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
                'png' => 'image/png',
                'gif' => 'image/gif',
            ),
            true
        )) {
            die(json_encode(array(
                'success' => false,
                'status' => "Invalid file format.",
                'files' => $_FILES
            )));

        }

        // You should name it uniquely.
        // DO NOT USE $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] WITHOUT ANY VALIDATION !!
        // On this example, obtain safe unique name from its binary data.
        if (!move_uploaded_file(
            $fileData['tmp_name'],
            sprintf('./gallery/%s.%s',
                basename($fileData['tmp_name']),
                $ext
            )
        )) {
            die(json_encode(array(
                'success' => false,
                'status' => "Failed to move uploaded file.",
                'files' => $_FILES
            )));

        }
//          $uploadFile = sprintf('./gallery/%s.%s',
//              sha1_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);

            $uploaddir = '/gallery/';
            $name = $fileData["tmp_name"];
        
            $fullPath = sprintf('gallery/%s.%s',
                basename($fileData['tmp_name']),
                $ext
            );
        
            array_push($pathArray, $fullPath);
        
//          echo '{"success": true, "status": "file Uploaded successfully", "filePath" : "$filePath"}';
//          _response(true, sprintf("%s", $fullPath));
//          echo(json_encode(array(
//              'success' => true,
//              'status' => "File is uploaded successfully.",
//              'filePath' => "$fullPath"
//          )));
}
//_log(sprintf("[multipart] Uploaded %s, %s, %d byte(s)", $fileName, $mimeType, $fileSize));
// _response(true, $pathArray);

            print_r(json_encode(array(
                'success' => true,
                'status' => "File is uploaded successfully.",
                'filePath' => "$fullPath"
            )));


?>
```

I didn't change much of his `_common.php` and `_config.php` which [can be found here](https://github.com/ivan-novakov/extjs-upload-widget/tree/master/public).

As you can see, at my PHP part, I am trying to send the filePath of the uploaded file back to the ExtJS part, I need this for a database entry process. However, I don't know how to obtain this JSON Object back in my ExtJS code as the function only has 4 arguments (uploadPanel, manager, items, errorCount) and so far I haven't had luck guessing which one would contain the JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

I found a rather crude workaround to this issue. What I did was that I used the original filenames of the files uploaded as the filenames in the server's file system. This is **NOT** a good solution. If you need to save the filename to a database and the filename is a SQL Injection, then you'll have problems.

```
// You should name it uniquely.
// DO NOT USE $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] WITHOUT ANY VALIDATION !!
// On this example, obtain safe unique name from its binary data.
move_uploaded_file(
    $fileData['tmp_name'],
    sprintf('./gallery/%s',
    basename($fileData['name'])
```

In this case `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']` is `$fileData['name']`, check the start of my `foreach` loop.

As mentioned you shouldn't really use `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']` without checking and validating it first.

This question will still be open for answers.